# Cropping raster layer in Unidata THREDDS Data Server

Tags: raster, clip, thredds

How do I crop a raster layer in [Unidata THREDDS Data Server](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/tds/current/TDS.html)

The server sends out gridded data from netCDF files in the form of raster images. But these are not cropped to country boundaries. Is there a configuration in THREDDS data server which would crop the raster layers using a shapefile or geojson and then send out the raster image?

This is the current output:
[image: This is the current output]

Expectation is to get:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any settings in THREDDS data server.
Since I was using openlayers, I used prerender and postrender events of the raster layer to copy ocean pixels from a base layer and paste on top of it, which works great in my case.

```
var color1 = {  r:120,  g:204,  b:240 }
var tolerance = 77;
function isNeighborColor(color2, tolerance) {
  if(tolerance == undefined) {
      tolerance = 32;
  }

  return Math.abs(color1.r - color2.r) <= tolerance
      && Math.abs(color1.g - color2.g) <= tolerance
      && Math.abs(color1.b - color2.b) <= tolerance;
}

var opacityImage;
  var oceanImage;
  rasterLayer.on('prerender', function (e) {
    let ctx = e.context;
      var canvas = ctx.canvas;
      opacityImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      oceanImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      rgba = opacityImage.data;
      for (var i = 0; i < rgba.length; i+= 4) {
        let r=rgba[i],g=rgba[i+1],b=rgba[i+2];
        let col = {
          r:r,
          g:g,
          b:b
        }
        
        if(isNeighborColor(col,tolerance)){            
          opacityImage.data[i+3] = 0;
        }
      }
  });
  rasterLayer.on('postrender', function (e) {
    let ctx = e.context;  
    var canvas = ctx.canvas;      
    const opacityImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let oceanImageData = oceanImage.data;
    for (var i = 0; i < opacityImage.data.length; i+= 4) {            
      if(rgba[i+3] == 0) {
        // opacityImage.data[i+3] = 0;
        opacityImage.data[i] = oceanImageData[i];
        opacityImage.data[i+1] = oceanImageData[i+1];
        opacityImage.data[i+2] = oceanImageData[i+2];
        opacityImage.data[i+3] = oceanImageData[i+3];
      }
    }
    ctx.putImageData(opacityImage,0,0);
    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'multiply';
    ctx.restore();
      
  });
```

The output looks as follows

[image: cropped raster layer]